# Can you simulate a modbus slave via serial connection on node-red?

Tags: serial-port, node-red, modbus, rs485

I have managed to use node-red to simulate a slave device using a TCP connection, but now I want to do it via serial connection. I am using a dell gateway running mbpoll to simulate the master connected to a raspberry pi running node-red to simulate the slave via RS485. Is it possible for me to use node-red on the raspberry pi to simulate the slave device, so it responds to requests from the gateway with values like a sensor would?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your previous questions you are using `node-red-contrib-modbus`; this node does [not support Modbus RTU](https://github.com/BiancoRoyal/node-red-contrib-modbus/issues/127) as per the node descriptions:

[modbus-server](https://github.com/BiancoRoyal/node-red-contrib-modbus/blob/master/src/modbus-server.html#L95) - Node to provide a Modbus TCP server based on node-modbus (jsmodbus) for testing.
[modbus-flex-server](https://github.com/BiancoRoyal/node-red-contrib-modbus/blob/master/src/modbus-flex-server.html#L395) - Node to provide a flexible Modbus TCP server based on modbus-serial for testing.

There may be another module out there that does support RTU slaves but I am not aware of one. As such I think your options are:

- Modify the existing note to add support for RTP.
- Use a gateway. There may be software that will do this (its not all that complicated) but I've not found anything freely available. There are a range of hardward gateways (some fairly cheap) that support comms between an RTU master and a TCP slave - e.g. [1](https://www.usriot.com/products/modbus-rtu-modbus-tcp-gateway.html) or [2](https://www.moxa.com/en/products/industrial-edge-connectivity/protocol-gateways/modbus-tcp-gateways/mgate-mb3180-mb3280-mb3480-series).

Comment: I'm not so sure about this answer, because the Modbus-write node has the option for a serial connection. Is this meant for simulating the slave via rs485, or not?

Comment: @MattieG4 you are correct that the Modbus-write node supports serial connections. However when using this node you are acting as a modbus master/client (sending [write commands](https://github.com/BiancoRoyal/node-red-contrib-modbus/blob/master/src/modbus-write.html#L116) to slave(s)). Your question was about simulating a slave (referred to as a server in the spec; accepting requests from a master and responding) and for that you use the modbus-server/modbus-flex-server nodes which do not currently support serial connections (see the github issue I referenced).